# Hide Scrollbar for iFrame in HTML5 on Firefox without editing the SRC

Tags: html, firefox, scrollbar, hide

I've read all the similar questions about hiding a vertical scrollbar.

It seems to be a recurring issue that the tricks below work in IE and Chrome, but not Firefox.

For example:

- `overflow:hidden` on the iframe hasn't worked.
- adding a `div` with `overflow:hidden` around the iframe hasn't
  worked.
- using the `seamless` html5 class for the iframe hasn't worked.
- `scrolling="yes"` with `overflow:hidden` hasn't worked.
- `scrolling="no"` with the `overflow:hidden` (and without) hasn't
  worked.
- `iframe::-moz-scrollbar {display:none;}` hasn't worked.
- ...

Are there any working HTML/CSS tags for Firefox?
Do I have to switch to JS?

NOTE: I cannot edit the SRC file. I'm building my page in Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.3.

Here is the primary html for the SRC:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html id="ctl00_Html1" lang="en-us" dir="ltr" __expr-val-dir="ltr" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head id="ctl00_Head1">
<body class="v4master" onload="if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();" scroll="no">
</html>`

Thanks for your help!
Adam

---

Like @hobberwickey said...

I cannot hide the scrollbar because the contents of the page which I cannot edit are overflowing.

If there is a way to change this... all ears. :)

Comment: can we see an example of the DOM segment you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your HTML and CSS actually look like it's hard to say, but I'd wager a guess that you'll want to apply the styles,

position: relative or absolute;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;

to the html and body elements to a CSS file within the iframe, not within the parent window.

Comment: I cannot edit the HTML or CSS of the page inside the frame. I can only edit the page holding the frame.

Comment: If the page within the iframe is overflowing the bounds that you set for it, scrollbars will appear within the iframe. If you can't edit the CSS of that, then there's nothing you can do except increase the size of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for me it worked with:
 width="100%" height="1000px" scrolling="yes" style=" display:inline;overflow-y:hidden;"

Answer (score 0):

The reason that scrollbar are showing is because there is somthing to scroll. So don't do to difficult about it and remove the scrolling content. With other words make your content smaller then the iframe where in must display. Make the body even with the showing content and make the iframe a fraction larger. and there will be no scrollbar, because there is nothing to scroll. If there is no tag/attribute for it, you must not create a reason for a using one.

Roberto Philippo.